# i need to remotely accsess sumsung s5 through windows

Tags: gps, remote-control

I'm sure you all are tired of reading this kind of question, but I'm seriously desperate. I using a Samsung Galaxy S5 sport, rooted. I've tried androidlost, lookout, where's my phone, and they don't work because they weren't installed before I lost access. I have called Samsung, google, sprint, and each numerous times. My phone is still on, I can call it and it rings. ADM says it's ringing when Im trying to locate it, but ya my phone is lost/stolen and I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Google account on a PC. Pull up your account security setting. Look for finding my device. Probably won't work if you already tried talking to Google. Then go to your photos (In your browser) look at all your photos. If there was any photo, video, screenshot taken you can look at it and depend on your settings, you should be able to get a geocode with a timestamp for the exact location of anything taken. You can then postcode into GMaps and switch to satellite view and see where your phone is located at the time and place of the pic. Then go to the PlayStore on a PC, log in. Now from the PlayStore you can now load any App you want onto your device from there. You are going to need to try and fool whoever has your device, so load a bunch of picture apps to try and get them to take picks. The apps will load on your device, but they have to be opened on there end since you did not set them up before hand ie. teamview would be awesome if setup before hand. 
Last, setup any type of Android with the same account. If you can, buy a through away phone. Now you can mirror all the activity of your Google apps (if they did not log you out)